# Unrecognized parameter name 'interior-point' in optimset

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to execute following code in MATLAB R2018a. It worked perfectly in MATLAB 2014, but `optimset` seems to be depreciated, so it has been deleted. What to use instead?

```
F = [-310 -250 -450 -370];
A = [6 4 10 9];
b = [86];
lb = zeros(4,1);
options = optimset('LargeScale','off','interior-point','on');
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = linprog(f,A,b,[],[],lb,[],[],options);
```

That's the error:

> Error using `optimset` (line 249)
>   Unrecognized parameter name `'interior-point'`.  Please see the options table in the documentation for a list of acceptable option parameters. Note that some parameters are only supported by OPTIMOPTIONS. [Link to options table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html)
>
> Error in `Untitled` (line 5)
>   `options = optimset('LargeScale','off','interior-point','on');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optimset` still works, but the available options have changed.  Nonetheless you should probably update the code to use `optimoptions`.  There is a discussion about [Choose Between optimoptions and optimset](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions-and-optimset.html) in the doc.

```
options = optimoptions('linprog');
options.Algorithm = 'interior-point';
```

The available options for `linprog` can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html#buusznx-options)